# Minitoc settings + \hfill in \subsection

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minitoc

I'm trying to make a note book on LaTeX for a language course.
For this I sort my vocabulary lists by theme.
As you can see in the example below,
I use a `\hfill` inside the \subsection command to make the title of the theme in the two language.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{a5paper}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%command to print the acutal minitoc
\newcommand{\printmyminitoc}{
        \setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 
        \begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[rounded corners,align=left,fill=black]{%
        \color{white}%
        \begin{minipage}{10cm}%minipage trick
        \noindent\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
        \end{minipage}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\end{center}
        }


\begin{document}


\chapter{Giới thiệu \hfill Se pr\'esenter }

\startcontents[chapters]
\printmyminitoc


\section{Vocabulaire - Từ ngữ}

\subsection{Nghề nghiệp \hfill Profession}

\noindent Bác sĩ \hfill Médecin\\
Y tá \hfill Infirmier\\
Luật sư \hfill Avocat\\
Kỹ sư \hfill Ingénieur

\subsection{Nơi làm việc \hfill Lieu de travail}

\noindent Bệnh viện \hfill Hôpital\\
Tòa án \hfill Cours de Justice\\
Trường đại học \hfill Université\\
Ngân hàng \hfill Banque


\end{document}
```

Since the size of my notes are increasing pretty much, I tried to use mini Table of Contents at the beginning of each chapter.
I found out a code on the internet, but as you can see, the result isn't really satisfying because of `\hfill`.

I wondered if it was possible to create a command `\subsection` which take two arguments instead of one.
*e.g.* `\subsection{Nghe nghiep}{Profession}`. It would show me the same result when I begin a subsection but in the mini-ToC, it  should take and show only the first or the second argument.

Also, in this mini-ToC, the margin is different on the left and the right,
how can I do to increase the margin to the right or remove the indentation to the left?

I'm open to solutions that gives me a nicer mini-ToC.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the optional argument like `\subsection[Nghề nghiệp]{Nghề nghiệp \hfill Profession}`. For adjusting the margins use `\hspace*{-1.6pc}` just before `minipage` and make node's width equal to text width.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{a5paper}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%command to print the acutal minitoc
\newcommand{\printmyminitoc}{
        \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
        \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[rounded corners,align=left,fill=black,minimum width=\textwidth]{%
        \color{white}%
        \hspace*{-1.6pc}
        \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}%minipage trick
        \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
        \end{minipage}%
        };
      \end{tikzpicture}
       \end{center}%
        }


\begin{document}


\chapter[Giới thiệu]{Giới thiệu \hfill Se pr\'esenter }

\startcontents[chapters]
\printmyminitoc


\section{Vocabulaire - Từ ngữ}

\subsection[Nghề nghiệp]{Nghề nghiệp \hfill Profession}

\noindent Bác sĩ \hfill Médecin\\
Y tá \hfill Infirmier\\
Luật sư \hfill Avocat\\
Kỹ sư \hfill Ingénieur

\subsection[Nơi làm việc]{Nơi làm việc \hfill Lieu de travail}

\noindent Bệnh viện \hfill Hôpital\\
Tòa án \hfill Cours de Justice\\
Trường đại học \hfill Université\\
Ngân hàng \hfill Banque


\end{document}
```

[image]